# Unable to disable/enable the check boxes on first select (click) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is if you select any of the check box (payee) - another rows with same column checkboxes should be be disable/enabled.

- Issue #1: I am unable to disable/enable the check boxes on first select. But working on second click if you select any checkbox.
- Issue #2: If I load the page again the value with check box which is previously checked is showing as disable with checked. I need it disable with unchecked.

Below is my code:

```
function onPayeeChkChange() {

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tblHousehold tr td#tdpayee input:checkbox').click(function(){

        var $inputs = $('#tblHousehold tr td#tdpayee input:checkbox')                            
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
                    }else{
                         $inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
                         }

                       });
                            });

                      }
```

I am not sure what I have missed.

Comment: Try using the change event instead of click

Comment: changed onchange instead click...but doesn't help.

Comment: Working fine with IE not Chrome on First click In my code, is there anything I have missed, But I just added below one statement in IF and one statement in else...see below,,
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$inputs.not(this).attr('checked', false);
$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
$(this).attr('checked',true);
}
else{
$inputs.removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Note: if you disable a checkbox, you will not be able to re-use it afterwards. If you must disable it, just add `.prop('disabled', true)` within the loop.

```js
$(function () {
    $(':checkbox').click(function () {
   var input = $(this), td = input.closest('td'), table = td.closest('table');
        // get index of the cell relative to its parent row
        var i = td.index();
        // loop through each row
        $('tr', table).each(function () {
         // uncheck the row's ith cell's checkbox
         $('td:eq(' + i + ') :checkbox', this).not(input).prop('checked', false);
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```